# Question about finding specific data using wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use CASE statement in my SQL to extract specific piece of information.
The field contains two words that I have to extract, however I need to have different result if one word is there, if a second word is there or if they are both in there in any combination.
Those fields will have different words between the words I'm trying to export.

So my code goes like this:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN CustRef3 like '%TL%' THEN 'TL'
WHEN CustRef3 like '%ADR%' THEN 'ADR'

WHEN CustRef3 in ('%ADR%,%TL%') THEN 'TL,ADR' 
// I know this one is wrong, I tried few different ways //

END AS "Attributes2".
```

I am getting TL when there is TL in the field, and I am getting ADR when there is ADR in that field.
How can I get ADR/TL if both words are in that field ?

Tried my query, expected to get right result.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `WHEN CustRef3 LIKE '%TL%' AND CustRef3 LIKE '%ADR%'` work? You might have to put it as the first part of the CASE statement, though , to ensure it takes precedence over the other conditions that would also be true.

Comment: Omg thank you, I did that already but I forgot to add it first, and I was wondering why is it not working. Big thanks !

Comment: Yeah, the order matters. If any previous cases would be true, the `CASE` statement simply exists and doesn't evaluate the remaining paths.

Comment: Fyi case is an *expression* not a *statement*

Comment: @DaleK Thanks :) My bad for using the wrong term

Answer (score 1):

In your case expression you just need to use AND.

```
WHEN CustRef3 like '%ADR%' AND CustRef3 like '%TL%' THEN 'TL,ADR'
```

Keep in mind that using leading wildcards your query is nonSARGable and the performance is going to suffer horribly. Also it is very likely you may return false positives because those search strings are really short. But that would up to you to determine based on your actual data.

Comment: This will work, but I kind of expect this is a shortened version, where there could be many of these.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree. I have a feeling that the entire approach is probably a bit brittle and prone to lots of fiddling.

Comment: Hi, that worked after adding it at the beginning of case statement. I was playing around with it constantly changing last bit and I was wondering why it doesn't work :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```sql
CASE WHEN CustRef3 like '%TL%' AND CustRef3 like '%ADR%'  THEN 'TL,ADR'
     WHEN CustRef3 like '%ADR%' THEN 'ADR'
     WHEN CustRef3 like '%TL%'  THEN 'TL'
     ELSE '' END  AS "Attributes2"
```

CASE expressions work like `if ... else if ... else`  statements in other languages: they take the first matching branch.

Comment: Hi, that worked, thank you a lot. I made mistake adding this at the end, and I was wondering why it doesn't work. :)